# DataTable TwoWay binding with DataGrid.

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I've got DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ResultSet, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="14"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

ResultSet property is some DataTable.

When I edit some cell this changes does not reflect on ResultSet. 
How can i fix that? 
Thanks!